# FIR Filter for image resampling by non integer factor

Tags: image-processing, filter, interpolation, convolution

Hello the title of this questions says it all. I do not find any leads to how one can design a FIR filter for image interpolation to upsample it or downsample it by a non integer factor.

Imagine I want to downscale an image by a 1.5 factor with cubic interpolation, how can I create the FIR filter? And how should I do the convolution with this FIR filter (if it is possible without zero padding)?

Any help or explanation is welcome and MUCH appreciated!

Comment: You didn’t find anything about this because it’s not posible. You need different interpolation (filter) weights at each output point.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/48997/33605 Please don’t cross-post, it’s against the rules. The DSP site is the better place for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You didn’t find anything about this because it’s not posible. You need different interpolation (filter) weights at each output point.

– Cris Luengo